# How to disable 'Download Complete' notification using selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to automate a functionality on my webpage.
I am downloading certain files using selenium. But as soon  as a download completes, I can see a pop up notification on my web page that the download is complete.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkX3U.png)

Kindly suggest using selenium, I can I remove this pop up notification?

I am setting the following firefox profile:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downlodeLocation);
 firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
        "application/bin,application/binary,text/comma-separated-values,application/octet-stream,text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,text/html,text/plain,application/csv,text/anytext");
 firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
     "application/bin,application/binary,text/comma-separated-values,application/octet-stream,text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,text/html,text/plain,application/csv,text/anytext");
```

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: while downloading did u set the download location to some default value using profiles?

Comment: yes, I have..I am downloading it to a particular folder. Updated the original ques with my code.

Comment: In IE you can do one thing: View Downloads --> Options --> Uncheck Notify me when my downloads are complete

Comment: Not sure..but i have FF 43.0.1 and i don't see download complete pop-up..but as a last resort use either AutoIt / Robot class to do away with this issue

Comment: What are you actually testing by clicking on a download link? http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the browser settings

Type `about:config` in the address bar. Search for `browser.download.animateNotifications` or `browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete` and set them to false by right click -> toggle.

Comment: I can see browser.download.animateNotifications but disabling it is not working

Comment: @Anonymous You can't disable or there isn't any affect?

Comment: There isn't any affect.

Comment: http://www.ghacks.net/2013/04/21/hide-or-prolong-firefoxs-downloads-complete-notification/

go through this link

Comment: look at the all browser.download options